# Delete permission for authors to delete items they have created themselves but no other items

Tags: xm-cloud, permissions

In Sitecore `XM Cloud`, is there any way we can set delete permission for authors to delete items they have created themselves but no other items.

Preferably with no code customization.

Thanks
Shrutika

Answer (score 3):

this functionality doesn't exist without code customization in Sitecore XMC or Sitecore normal.

You can have such a functionality just if a specific user has rights to create/delete items just under a specific item X and other users doesn't create items under that X item.

Answer (score 0):

The condition to Disable delete button for an item is covered by following scenarios:

```
if (!obj.Access.CanDelete() || obj.Appearance.ReadOnly || Command.IsLockedByOther(obj))
      return CommandState.Disabled;
```

1. Readonly is checked on the item
2. Author do not has access to delete item
3. Item is locked by other user.

You can modify this condition to disable delete button for authors who have not created it. But there is no direct way I believe to achieve the same.